# Android WebView and NO_FAST_DRAW = false

Tags: android

I am testing a website which opens a new tab when url changes. I am trying to open that web site in a web view and reload the contents in the same view (not opening diff tab).

Foe specific events it does load new contents and throw error.

This is one of the url which does not open

```
http://xxx.net/abcd/tablet/tocSelector.html?VERSION=CURRENT&DOCNBR=757_AARD&DOCTYPE=SRM&MODEL=G123&PAGEKEY=TOC

03-12 09:09:02.060: V/webview(4731): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
03-12 09:09:02.500: V/webview(4731):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE
```

What can do to make all the urls open in a single webview ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
      YourActivity.this.setProgress(newProgress * 1000);
   }
}
webview.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
```

Comment: a little explanation might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. On bellow first line i was getting error "Android WebView and NO_FAST_DRAW = false".
After change to second line. it worked. the error was at createCustomAlert('wpt').
  SO the function which I was called look like a string. This err was coming. So please check at place of function calling place

onclick = 'createCustomAlert('wpt')'

onclick = 'createCustomAlert(3)'